# Keras predicting Python

Tags: python, keras

First of all I am new to Keras and ML.

I am trying https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/pretrained_word_embeddings.py example.

I saved the trained model using `model.save()`. Now I am writing a script to predict using another script:

```
model = load_model('./model.h5')

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NB_WORDS)
text = np.array(['some unseen text'])
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
data = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)

prediction = model.predict(np.array(data))
```

The above returns something like:

`[[  1.00000000e+00   2.66153551e-18   1.67506186e-15   1.33851482e-16
    2.85387820e-16   3.06079675e-15   1.34407281e-14   1.38863788e-15
    4.20352726e-16   1.28687439e-15   1.52688925e-16]]`

I would like to get the label names given in the training. Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the original labels?

Comment: Yes I do. The resulted list has 11 elements, I have 11 labels. But I am not sure how to relate the label names with the result. I cannot see a relationship.

Comment: `np.array(labels)[prediction.argmax(axis=1)]` Is this what you want?

Comment: You might want to get the labels from the classifier, in the order the classifier learned them.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am not sure what I need!
How do I get the labels from the classifier?
I tried np.array(labels), but it is always returning the first label.